# hat problem and probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There are 7 prisoners in the room. In the entrance all of them get hat in one of random 2 colors: white or black. They are sitting in the circle and the light on. All of them see hat color of the rest but can't see himself. They will be free if at least one of them say the right color of himself hat color and no one is wrong (they could see the answer or no). The other prisoners can't hear the answer. 
How to find the best strategy with the best probability?

Comment: I heard that the best is 7/8 but I have no idea how to find in. Any better than 1/2 will be appreciated:)

Comment: If the colors are assigned at equal probability and independently, you will not be able do better than 1/2.

Comment: @ablmf: This problem is interesting precisely because most people initially have this erroneous intuition (I did, too). See my answer to this question and the duplicate question to see why and how you can do a lot better than $\frac12$.

Answer (score 0):

Given a cyclic binary $1$-[covering code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_code) of length $7$, the prisoners can ensure that they're freed unless the hat assignment corresponds to one of the codewords. Each prisoner should form the two binary strings obtained by completing what she sees with the two possible colours of her hat. If one colour yields a codeword, she should guess the other colour; otherwise she should remain silent.

Since the code is $1$-covering, at least one prisoner will guess her colour, and she will guess correctly unless the hat assignment corresponds to a codeword. Thus the probability of failing is the proportion of words that are codewords.

A minimal cyclic binary $1$-covering code of length $7$ is given by $0000000$,  the seven permutations of $1101000$ and the complements of those eight strings, for a total of $16$ codewords and a probability $\frac{16}{128}=\frac18$ of failing , and thus $\frac78$ of being freed.